# Vue conditional v-on event prevent modifier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I use v-on's `.prevent` modifier when I use it dynamically?

```
<a
  href="#"
  class="modal-overlay"
  aria-label="Close"
  v-on="overlayClickClosesModal ? { click: () => closeModal() } : {}"
/>
```

I'm trying to stop the URL being appended with `/#`

I've tried

`v-on.prevent`

`v-on:prevent`

`v-on="overlayClickClosesModal ? { 'click.prevent':`

Answer (score 5):

It's much clearer  if you move the logic into a method:

```
<a href="#" @click="clickMethod">
```

And then make the check in the script part:

```
clickMethod (event) {
    if (this.overlayClickClosesModal) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

---

Why are you even adding the anchor to your link? It's not necessary and you can save yourself the work.

---

Dynamically adding modifiers does not seem to be supported in Vue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9417

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to replace the `.prevent` [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) with a direct call to [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) inside the event handler:

```html
<a
  href="#"
  class="modal-overlay"
  aria-label="Close"
  v-on:click="maybeCloseModal"
/>
```

with the `maybeCloseModal` method defined in your `methods` section as e.g.:

```js
maybeCloseModal: function (event) {
  if (this.overlayClickClosesModal) {
    event.preventDefault();  // this will do the same thing as .prevent
    this.closeModal();
  }
}
```

But honestly, I'm not sure if this is really a sensible thing to do in your case anyway, since the default behavior of clicking your link doesn't seem useful in any way.  So you might want to just prevent it unconditionally, e.g. like this:

```html
<a
  href="#"
  class="modal-overlay"
  aria-label="Close"
  v-on:click.prevent="overlayClickClosesModal && closeModal()"
/>
```

For that matter, you'd probably want to make the `aria-label` conditional on that same boolean flag, too.  Or maybe even just have two different versions of the overlay — one clickable and one not clickable — and choose between them using `v-if`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the same event (`click`) conditionally, you could simply do :

```
    v-on:click.prevent="overlay ? close(): {}"
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      overlay: true

    }
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      console.log("close")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <a href="#" class="modal-overlay" aria-label="Close" v-on:click.prevent="overlay ? close(): {}" >close</a>
</div>
```